# r using renv to reproduce project, some library in renv.lock not in the folder /renv/library

Tags: r, renv

I was new in using renv

I noticed that there were many packages in the renv.lock but were not installed in renv/library folder, Is those library too basic and won't need to be installed?

For Example, here is the installed library list in renv/library

[image]

But There are several packages like MASS,Matrix which were listed in renv.lock 's json info, but they didn't show up in the folder list.

Comment: There are a bunch of packages that come with R itself that you do not install separately from CRAN. you can see those with `installed.packages(priority="high")` So as long as you have the right version of R, those packages will be up to date. You'll see that both MASS and Matrix are in that list.

Comment: Ok,I see the logic here